# Trying to bind DateTime.Now in gridview

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, itemtemplate, databound

I am using Visual Web Developer Express 2013 and have created a gridview.  When I update other values in the grid, I want txtDate to show the time the values were updated.
I set it up as an item template.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="txtDate" SortExpression="txtDate">
<itemtemplate><asp:label id="txtDate" runat="server" 
 text="<%# Bind DateTime.Now.ToString()%>"></asp:label>    
</itemtemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

When I use the above code without Bind - I get the current time displaying.  I added Bind so that the current date would insert into the database and I  get the following error;
Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

I'm trying to figure out the best way to insert the date when the values are updated.  I also tried adding txtDate as a hidden field but that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you post your entire Gridview markup?

Comment: why don't you update it in your stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uses `GetDate()` function directly in the insert query, you don't need to show this to the user, because its just for logging purpose as far as I have understood what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you so much - it worked - a very simple solution!